# Macro to concatenate another macro

Tags: c++, concatenation, c-preprocessor

Consider the following:

```
#define asd(a, b) a ## _ ## b
#define concat(a, b) a ## b
```

When I do:

```
concat(__, asd(x, y));
```

I would expect to get

```
__x_y
```

But no, the asd part is not evaluated as a macro. What am I supposed to do? I also tried directly with

```
__ ## asd(x, y)
```

But no, that doesn't work either. Is there any way to get what I need, i.e., the result of `asd(x, y)` to be used in `concat` instead of the explicit `"asd(x, y)"` expression?